# raise ValueError("np.nan is an invalid document, expected byte or "

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, valueerror, countvectorizer

I am using `CountVectorizer()` in scikit-learn for vectorizing the feature sequence. I am receiving an error as below:

```
ValueError: np.nan is an invalid document, expected byte or unicode string.
```

I am using an example csv dataset with two columns `CONTENT` and `sentiment`.

Here's my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("train.csv",encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
X, y = df.CONTENT, df.sentiment

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)
print X_train, y_train

vect = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,3), analyzer='word', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
print vect
X=vect.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)
y=vect.fit(X_test) 
print vect.get_feature_names()
```

Here is the error message in full:

```
File "C:/Users/HP/cntVect.py", line 28, in <module>
    X=vect.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 839, in fit_transform
    self.fixed_vocabulary_)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 762, in _count_vocab
    for feature in analyze(doc):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 241, in <lambda>
    tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 121, in decode
    raise ValueError("np.nan is an invalid document, expected byte or "

ValueError: np.nan is an invalid document, expected byte or unicode string.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

replace NaN's with spaces - this should make `CountVectorizer` happy:

```
X, y = df.CONTENT.fillna(' '), df.sentiment
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not handling the `NaN`, i.e. "not a number" aptly.
Use python's `fillna()` method to fill/replace the missing or `NaN` values in your pandas `dataframe` with your desired value.

Hence, instead of:

```
X, y = df.CONTENT, df.sentiment
```

Use:

```
X, y = df.CONTENT.fillna(' '), df.sentiment
```

in which `NaN`'s are replaced by `<spaces>`.

Answer (score 2):

What I can guess from your question is certain fields in the content are empty. You can follow the fillna method or drop the columns by df[df["Content"].notnull()]. This will give you the dataset where there are not NAN values.