i got ValueError: np.nan is an invalid document, expected byte or unicode string
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

# Read the first Excel file with Business codes and descriptions
df1 = pd.read_excel("E:/file1.xlsx")

# Read the second Excel file with Business licenses
df2 = pd.read_excel("E:/file2.xlsx")

# Initialize a TF-IDF Vectorizer
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()

# Combine the business descriptions and licenses into a single list
combined_text = list(df1['Business descriptions']) + list(df2['Business licences'])

# Fit and transform the TF-IDF Vectorizer on the combined text
tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(combined_text)

# Calculate the cosine similarity between the TF-IDF vectors
cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)

# Get the indices of the business descriptions and licenses in the cosine similarity matrix
desc_indices = range(len(df1))
lic_indices = range(len(df1), len(df1) + len(df2))

# Create a dictionary to store the mappings between business descriptions and licenses
mapping_dict = {}

# Iterate over the business descriptions and find the best matching license based on cosine similarity
for desc_idx in desc_indices:
    best_match_idx = max(lic_indices, key=lambda x: cosine_sim[desc_idx][x])
    mapping_dict[df1.loc[desc_idx, 'Business codes']] = df2.loc[best_match_idx - len(df1), 'Business licences']

# Create a new dataframe from the mapping dictionary
mapped_df = pd.DataFrame(list(mapping_dict.items()), columns=['Business codes', 'Mapped Business licences'])

# Save the mapped data to a new Excel file
mapped_df.to_excel('mapped_data.xlsx', index=False)


hi, I have 2 excel file. One of them has two columns, Business codes and business descriptions. The Excel file 2 has a one column, Business licences. I want to do semantic text mapping on the business description with business licenses on the common words between them. this is the code i got from chatgpt, and i got the error: ValueError: np.nan is an invalid document, expected byte or unicode string.
thanks for your help.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Does this answer your question? TfidfVectorizer in scikit-learn : ValueError: np.nan is an invalid document or https://stackoverflow.com/q/49259305/12846804

Please see [mre]: your question is lacking input data and they probably contain the root cause.
